# Is is possible to change the size of PixelAccess in python?

Tags: python, image, crop

I was cropping a without the using crop() function of PIL (just for fun) but I cannot find a way to reduce the size of PixelAccess.

I am able to change the color of the desired section but I am not able to just get the desired section.

Can anyone guide me how to get just the required section from the image?

```
from PIL import Image

i = Image.open('astro.bmp')
pixels = i.load()
width, height = i.size

all_pixels = []
print(type(pixels))

#image resolution is 1024 x 768
for x in range(width) :
    for y in range(height) :
        ap = pixels[x, y]
        all_pixels.append(ap)

center_x = 40
center_y = 40
crop_width = 180
crop_height = 180


#for cropping
for x in range(crop_width) :
    center_y = 40
    for y in range(crop_height) :
        pixels[center_x, center_y] = all_pixels[768 * center_x + center_y]
        center_y += 1
    center_x += 1

center_x = 40
# to change color of the required region
for x in range(crop_width) :
    center_y = 40
    for y in range(crop_height) :
        pixels[center_x, center_y] = 253
        center_y += 1
    center_x += 1

i.save('out.bmp')
```

Comment: Add some code you have tried to allow people to help you :) PS - welcome to SO!

Comment: thanks @garfbradaz, I have added whole the code.